# d3-cloud renders only one word from list of words

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, d3-cloud

I have been trying to create an simple example for [d3-cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud), but somehow it's not working as expected. I am passing a list of words, but d3-cloud only renders one word. I have inspected svg element too and there is only single text element in it. Any help is really appreciated.

[Please find the link for plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/xi43RGVHgVlu6jwETBvI/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `fontSize` method. Look at [my fork of your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uo6SDnUcNwEauuUlkS6D?p=preview).

```
  let d3cloud = d3.layout.cloud()
                .size([width,height])
                .rotate(0)
                .fontSize(40) // <-- !!!
                .on("end", this.drawCloud)
                .words(entity_list);
```